# Too low voltage at the output of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, voltage-divider

I'm using [MCP6231](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001881G%20MCP6231-20%20uA%20300%20kHz%20Rail-to-Rail%20Op%20Amp.pdf) as voltage follower exactly like in pic below. When voltage at non inverting input is at level of 1.5V the output has only 0.8V. I have put 100nF ceramic capacitor close to the supply pin. Circuit is powered by 3,3V LDO regulator. Do you have any idea where may be source of this error? I use Vout pin to drive REF pin in INA333.

[image: MCP6241]

EDIT:
Here is pic of my PCB layout

[image: PCB]

[image: SCH]

Comment: Looks like it should work. What resistor values?

Comment: Should work. There are three different pinouts for the SOT-23, maybe you have the wrong one.

Comment: Resistors are 2k ohm 0.1%, im sure that pinout is ok.

Comment: What's the load on VREF?

Comment: 10k ohm connected to GND and drives INA333 REF pin

Comment: Check the value of that 10K resistor. Maybe it's 50 or 100 ohms rather than 10K. Should be marked 103 or 01C.

Comment: Im sure that this is 10k, i tried to unsolder this resistor and the voltage didnt react at all. Shall i place additional resistor between output and reversing input of the op-amp? Lets say ~2k ohm?

Comment: Just to check, you don't have **anything** else connected to REF node (like a capacitor not shown)? Also your pinout appears to be MCP6241U or MCP6231U not MCP6241/6231 so the code should be BSxx or BLxx, not BJxx or BQxx.

Comment: There is nothing more connected. You are right, I made mistake in first post, op-amp is 
MCP6241UT-E/OT. In this project I also have LP filter designed with this amp and its working fine.

Comment: Then my only suggestion is that the op-amp is defective. Check the expected resistances when you have it off and replace it, would be my path forward.

Comment: ok, i will try do this tommorow. Thanks you for your time :)

Comment: Maybe when you have it off, try to drive the output node to 1.5V with 100 ohms or whatever in series just to make sure there isn't some other issue with the board. I have seen hairline shorts with resistance in this range and you have a lot of pours and thus opportunities for shorts. Maybe hold it up to a strong light and look at it through a magnifier or microscope before removing the op-amp.

Comment: I did replace this op-amp and now everything works fine. Thanks for help.